# Cloud Endpoints Portal requires GCP / IAM permissions, otherwise the user gets No APIs are available that you have permission to view

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-apis-explorer

I have Cloud Endpoints Framework implemented in my App Engine project, and I'd like to migrate from the deprecated API Explorer to the new Endpoints Portal.

The thing is, unlike the old API Explorer, the Endpoints Portal is not accessible to everybody. When a user that has no access to the GCP project tries to access the portal, he gets:

> No APIs are available that you have permission to view

[image]

Is there a way to make the cloud endpoints portal public, and let each endpoints manage the authentication part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to the Endpoints Portal cannot be made public.

You can find a complete discussion on this topic at this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-endpoints/-GrnDqyauiI).

A possible solution is also proposed in the discussion:

> One other option in the meantime is that you could use Google groups for authentication --- that is, you can add a Google group as "Service Consumer", and then every member of that group can view the API + portal.

But if what you want is to make access completely public, not only to your customers / users, this solution is not the best, you should opt for another one.

[SwaggerUI](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) could be an excellent solution: it’s automatically generated from your OpenAPI document and it's accessible to any user.

Comment: You're right, there is also a feature request for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/127623472